# What catalysts can be used to decompose nitrous oxide?

Tags: decomposition

Constraints:

1. I'm going to need to use a lot of this stuff in various locations, so I'd prefer it not be expensive (leaving out things like platinum, palladium, and rhodium.)
2. While I don't believe I can get a "room-temperature" catalyst (I'm always willing to be proven wrong!) I need this to begin the decomposition reaction at as low a temperature as possible.  This will allow electric heating to get it up to heat as rapidly as possible, using as little valuable battery or fuel cell power (I haven't decided yet) as possible.
3. The catalyst will be mounted *near* (not in!) a rocket engine combustion chamber, with a flame temperature of 3,553 K.

This will be used to decompose $\ce{N2O}$ as follows:

$$\ce{2N2O -> 2N2 + O2 + heat}$$

This will (re)light `LOX/LCH4` engines in-flight.  I'm thinking about a second of $\ce{N2O}$ decomposition should touch off `LOX/LCH4` nicely, then cut the $\ce{N2O}$.  Landing engines will need to be lit mid-flight for a safe touchdown, and it may be necessary to relight the lifting engines for some reason, which means I'd need to have this catalyst in at least 12 locations.

8 in landing engines and  4 either in lifting engines or 1in aerospike with redundant ignition.  I'm not married to the aerospike idea yet, I'm still trying to figure out how to Regeneratively cool the center truncated spike while allowing for a "base bleed" to minimize the effects of the low pressure recirculation area at the flat end of the spike.

If I can't crack that, it will be back to four bell-nozzle lifting engines. So, minimum twelve catalyst beds per instance.